# d3 svg how to create a polyline with an arrow at the end

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to add an arrow at the end of a `polyline` but it scales incorrectly. I am relatively new to d3 and svg so I hope some can figure out how to do this:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbbb4gdL/)

```
    var w = 300;
    var h = 300;
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

    //arrow
    svg.append("svg:defs")
        .append("svg:marker")
        .attr("id", "arrow")
        .attr("refX", 6)
        .attr("refY", 6)
        .attr("markerWidth", 30)
        .attr("markerHeight", 30)
        .attr("orient", "auto")
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", "M 0 0 12 6 0 12 3 6")
        .style("fill", "black");


    //line              
    svg.append("line")
      .attr("x1", 100)
      .attr("y1", 100)
      .attr("x2", 200)
      .attr("y2", 100)
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");

    // polyline
    svg.append("polyline")
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "blue")
        .attr("stroke-width", "2")
        .attr("points", "05,05 15,05 15,15 25,15 25,25 35,25")
        .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");
```

Comment: why do you say it scales incorrectly?
You have added a stroke width of 2 pixel in polyline that is why the arrow comes big.
https://jsfiddle.net/dh75o5ec/

in the line you have given stroke-width as 1 so the arrow marker comes as expected.
I have corrected it here https://jsfiddle.net/qq3gbajr/ hope this is what you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you. That did it. As I said I am new to the whole svg thing so do not understand it completely yet.

Comment: are there any good books for this whole svg thing?